# Beginner question: Reading a resource text file on MacOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to this and apologize if it's basic. I have tried to research and I either get iOS posts, or old Xcode posts - none that are helping me with a basic need.

I want to have a bundled text file in my Swift/SwiftUI/MacOS app. It's just a text file, say sample.txt

I want to read it and do something with it.

I did the following:

1. Created a folder called "Resources" in my project
2. Added the text file - sample.txt

In my SwiftUI code, I did the following

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
          print("...getting resource")
          let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
          print(contents)
     } catch {
          // contents could not be loaded
          print(error)
       }
     } else {
        print("no such file!")
     }
```

And I get `no such file`

I changed the `forResource: "sample"` to `forResource: "Resource/sample"` and that didn't help either.

What should I be doing?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your resources folder / the file are actually being included in the final built app?

Comment: Right now I'm only testing with build/run from Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to create an extra folder `Resources`. Just add the file to the project. It will be moved into the `Resources` folder of the app while being built.

And make sure that the Target Membership checkbox of the file is checked.